# How do I disable input element whose type is submit?

Tags: html, input

I know the following works:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
<button disabled="disabled">
```

But how would you disable this?

```
<input type="submit" ....>
```

Any idea? Do I have to use javascript?

Thanks.

---

Okay. It might have been my Firefox problem. I swear I did use the same synatx. 
Thanks, and sorry for such a silly question?

Comment: As an addition, in case you want to dynamically disable a button using jQuery, here's a basic example : [http://jsfiddle.net/6nSfu/](http://jsfiddle.net/6nSfu/)

Comment: Thanks D-Lo. It was a nice example. I am actually using it for another thing :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `disabled="disabled"` on `input`'s that are of type `submit`:

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: It's weird. I definitely did use this. I am using firefox 9.0.1 and it's not allowing me to do it. Maybe I need to reinstall my FF.

Answer (score 8):

Just use:

```
<input type="submit" disabled>
```

Here’s a demo: http://jsbin.com/agojoy/edit#html,live

Note that `disabled` is a boolean attribute. There are variations in syntax, but they all have the same effect:

```
<input type="submit" disabled=disabled>
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled">
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I did use this, and synatx was right. I might have hit some really nasty software problem on my own. I was like "no way... it has to be working..." Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to dynamically disable a button, you do need to use javascript.

Attach to the click event and set the control to disabled.

If you just want to do so in the HTML, the `disabled` attribute works just as well:

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: It's weird. I definitely did use this. I am using firefox 9.0.1 and it's not allowing me to do it. Maybe I need to reinstall my FF.That's why I ask.